# I got a hard algorithm problems with some binary operations, is it anyone can help me with that in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a sequence `a_1, a_2, ..., a_n`. I can perform `k` operations. The steps for each operation are as follows:

1. I can choose any of the numbers `a_i (1 <= i <= n)`
2. Change the lowest set bit of `a_i` from 1 to 0 in binary

I want to know what the minimum value is of the sum of the sequences after k operations?

enter:
The first line enters two integers `n,k`
Next, enter `n` positive integers to represent my sequence
Output:
Output a number representing the answer.

```
enter:
2 1
8 7
```

```
Output:
7
```

**illustrate:**

8 in binary is 1000
The binary version of 7 is 111

If I perform an operation on 8, the sequence becomes [0,7], and the sum is 7

If I perform an operation on 7, the sequence becomes [8,6], and the sum is 14

So the minimum value is 7

```
enter:
2 2
9 6
```

```
Output:
6
```

Explanation: The binary number of 9 is 1001. Change the two 1's of 9 into 0 in two steps, leaving only 6

I would like you to provide the ideas and code if you can.

---

actually now my thinking is that The problem can be transformed into distributing all k operations on each number so that the sum of the values that can be subtracted is maximized. For example, there are three operations now, and the two numbers are 7 (111) and 24 (11000). Then it must be divided into two times for 24 and one operation for 7 to gain the most profit.
Observe that k is relatively small, and the number of operations that can be performed on a number does not exceed 30 times at most (the binary representation of a number does not exceed 30 1s at most), then it can be regarded as a template question for a grouped backpack, and k is the backpack Capacity, total n Group items, each number is a group, the volume of each item in the group is the number of assigned operations, and the value is the sum of the values that can be subtracted. Then the number of items in a group depends on how many 1's there are in the binary representation of this number. For example, the 2 items produced by 6 are {value: 2, volume: 1}, {value: 6, volume: 2}. But looks quite complicated...still need a lot of work.

Comment: So, op (2) changes the lowest _set_ bit to zero, whichever that is? And it can be executed multiple times, on the same number? In this case, wouldn't something like this be more or less optimal? 1) select number with fewest 1s in binary; 2) change 1s to 0s; 3) repeat. (Until not all 1s can be made 0s, in this case, select the smallest number)

Comment: no. like sequence 9,6 . For 9, the binary one is 1001, 6 is 110. So you try to operate k times(here k=2) to make the sum of the sequence lowest. So for 9,6 ,first time is to change the 9 to 1000, and then change it to 0000. then the sum of the sequence is 6(because 9 is 0 now.)

Comment: @tobias_k No: 2 2 3 56 (3=11, 56=111000). You better change 56.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have the number 8 (0b1000) and you change the last bit from 0 to 1 you end up with 8, since the last bit was already 0. How do you end up having 7? Then you say "The binary number of 9 is 1001. Change the two 1's of 9 into 0, leaving only 6"  why are you changing two 1s to 0s here? and if you do, you will end with the number 0, not 6.  Could you clarify the operations, because they are not clear to me

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki You flip the last set bit.

Comment: Ok, I flip the last set bit of 8 to 0. Now I went from 0b1000 to 0b0000. Result is 0. The question says nothing about the last set bit (it talks about the last bit). And even if I do, the result won't be 7 but 0. In the comments the op says "first time is to change the 9 to 1000, and then change it to 0000" so it looks like from 9 (1001) goes to 8 (1000) an then to 0 (0000). Ok, we are flipping the last set bit. then how does 8 become 7 and not 0?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Where do you get 8 changing to 7? I don't see anything like that in the text. I see (8,7) changing to either (0,7) or (8,6).

Comment: Does it have to be in Python? It's a generic algorithm, which can be solved with many languages.

Comment: @9769953 Make allowances for imperfect command of English and/or terminology. The intent is clearly to change the last set bit.

Comment: @9769953 You can edit it.

Comment: It is actually a straightforward DP problem.

Comment: Can you provide the constraints of the problem? Maximum length of the input list, maximum van of k?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do whit a recursive approach:

```
#Assuming parsing is already done

def flipBit(number, n):
    return number ^ (1 << n)

def countTrailingZeros(number):
    if number == 0:
        return -1
    for i in range(32):
        mask = 1 << i
        if number & mask:
            return i
    return -1

def minSumAfterOperation(sequence, k):
    if k == 0:
        return sum(sequence)
    bestMin = -1
    minIndex = 0
    for index in range(len(sequence)):
        if sequence[index] == 0:
            continue
        save = sequence[index]
        sequence[index] = flipBit(sequence[index], countTrailingZeros(sequence[index]))
        currentMin = minSumAfterOperation(sequence, k - 1)
        sequence[index] = save
        if bestMin == -1 or bestMin > currentMin:
            bestMin = currentMin
            minIndex = index
        
    return bestMin
    
print(minSumAfterOperation([8, 7], 1))
print(minSumAfterOperation([9, 6], 2))
```

The code check the minimum value of a modified sequence with one operation and then calls itself with k - 1 operation on the resulting sequence. If no operation is to be performed simply return the sum of the sequence.

The main issue with this code will be performance wise as it is simply a bruteforce method.

Edit:

After some thoughts you can have something more optimized:

```
#Assuming parsing is already done

def flipBit(number, n):
    return number ^ (1 << n)

def countTrailingZeros(number):
    if number == 0:
        return -1
    for i in range(32):
        mask = 1 << i
        if number & mask:
            return i
    return -1
    
def perfomChainedOperation(number, k):
    for i in range(k):
        count = countTrailingZeros(number)
        number = flipBit(number, count)
    return number

def enumerateChainedOp(number, k):
    if number == 0 or k == 0:
        return []
    
    ops = []
    original = number
    for i in range(k):
        if number == 0:
            return ops
        
        count = countTrailingZeros(number)
        number = flipBit(number, count)
        ops.append((original - number)/(i + 1))
        
    return ops

def minSumAfterOperation(sequence, k):
    if k == 0:
        return sum(sequence)
    
    bestOp = 0
    bestOpIndex = 0
    bestIndex = -1
    for i, number in enumerate(sequence):
        ops = enumerateChainedOp(number, k)
        for j, op in enumerate(ops):
            if op > bestOp:
                bestOp = op
                bestIndex = i
                bestOpIndex = j
    
    sequence[bestIndex] = perfomChainedOperation(sequence[bestIndex], bestOpIndex + 1)
    return minSumAfterOperation(sequence, k - bestOpIndex - 1)
    
print(minSumAfterOperation([8, 7], 1))
print(minSumAfterOperation([9, 6], 2))
```

1. For each number in the sequence enumerate the ratio of the resulting loss after performing up to k operations on it, with the number of operations done
2. Compare each possible chain of operations on each number and take the highest and perform the corresponding number of operations on that number
3. Call the function with the resulting number of operations

This code will have way less recursive calls i think as the approach is less bruteforcy.

Edit: Fixed first anwser

Comment: Indeed the first solution produces an error. 

In the first loop of minSumAfterOperation we would need to add this check:

```
if sequence[index] == 0:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dynamic programming approach. With a linked list twist so you can find out how to get the optimal answer.

```
def int_to_bits_removed (n):
    answer = [0]
    m = 0
    trailing = 1
    while 0 < n:
        if 0 < (n % (2*trailing)):
            m += trailing
            answer.append(m)
            n -= trailing
        trailing += trailing
    return answer

def optimal_removed (numbers, k):
    # We have not gotten to any number of bits removed...
    best = [None] * (k + 1)

    # Except 0. The tuple is:
    #  (total value removed, last index removed from, bits, previous)
    best[0] = (0, None, None, None)
    max_filled = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        a = numbers[i]
        removal = int_to_bits_removed(a)
        # Go from most to least bits previously removed
        # ...so that we are looking at old values.
        for j in range(max_filled, -1, -1):
            for l in range(1, min(len(removal), k + 1 - j)):
                if best[j+l] is None or best[j+l][0] < best[j][0] + removal[l]:
                    best[j+l] = (best[j][0] + removal[l], i, l, best[j])
                    if max_filled < j+l:
                        max_filled = j+l
    return best[max_filled]

print(optimal_removed([9, 6, 5], 3))
```

This will print:

```
(11, 1, 1, (9, 0, 2, (0, None, None, None)))
```

Which means:

```
(11,                         # total removed is 11
  1,                         # removed from the 6 at index 1
  2,                         # 1 bit
  ( 9,                       #   previously removed is 9
    0,                       #   removed from the 9 at index 0
    2,                       #   removed 2 bits
    (0, None, None, None)))  #     root node
```

Therefore this tells you both how much you removed in 3 operations, and what those operations actually were.

Answer (score 0):

I've modeled the problem using [`pulp`](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/).

Here is how it works:

The initial variables are:

```py
num_operations = 3
vals = [7, 24]
```

So first we create matrix (each row coresponds to value, each column for one binary operation):

```py
 [[7, 6, 4, 0],     # in binary: 0b111, 0b110, 0b100, 0b000
  [24, 16, 0, 0]]   #            0b11000, 0b10000, 0b0, 0b0
```

But for our linear programming model we need to *maximize* the amount the binary operation subtracts from total value, so we change matrix to:

```
 [[1, 3, 7],
   ^  ^  ^
   |  |  \-- If we chose to do 3 binary operations on value 7, we subtract 7 from total value
   |  \----- If we chose to do 2 binary operations on value 7, we subtract 3 from total value
    \------- If we chose to do 1 binary operation  on value 7, we subtract 1 from total value

  [8, 24, 0]]
   # the same for value 24
```

Then we define our model:

```
my_problem = pulp.LpProblem("Binary Operations Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)

# we have one 0-1 binary variable for every choice
vars_ = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("choice", (val_num, operation_num), 0, 1, pulp.LpBinary)

# we maximize the amount subtracted from total value
my_problem += (pulp.lpSum([combs[i][j] * vars_[v][o] for i, v in enumerate(val_num) for j, o in enumerate(operation_num)]),"Maximize Gain",)

# contstraints:

# for every value we can have only one variable set to 1 at most.
for v in val_num:
    my_problem += pulp.lpSum([vars_[v][o] for o in operation_num]) <= 1

# we must not to exceed maximum number of operations
my_problem += (pulp.lpSum([vars_[v][o] * i for v in val_num for i, o in enumerate(operation_num, 1)])== num_operations, "Maximum number of operations",)
```

---

### The complete example:

```py
import re

import pulp


def remove_last_one(n):
    return int(re.sub(r"(.*)1", r"\g<1>0", bin(n)), 2)


num_operations = 3
vals = [7, 24]

val_num = [f"v{i}" for i in range(1, len(vals) + 1)]
operation_num = [f"o{i}" for i in range(1, num_operations + 1)]

combs = []
for v in vals:
    combs.append([v])
    for _ in range(num_operations):
        if combs[-1][-1] == 0:
            combs[-1].append(v)
        else:
            combs[-1].append(remove_last_one(combs[-1][-1]))
combs = [[v - vv for vv in l][1:] for v, l in zip(vals, combs)]


my_problem = pulp.LpProblem("Binary Operations Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)

vars_ = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("choice", (val_num, operation_num), 0, 1, pulp.LpBinary)
my_problem += (
    pulp.lpSum(
        [
            combs[i][j] * vars_[v][o]
            for i, v in enumerate(val_num)
            for j, o in enumerate(operation_num)
        ]
    ),
    "Maximize Gain",
)

my_problem += (
    pulp.lpSum(
        [
            combs[i][j] * vars_[v][o]
            for i, v in enumerate(val_num)
            for j, o in enumerate(operation_num)
        ]
    ),
    "Maximize Gain",
)

for v in val_num:
    my_problem += pulp.lpSum([vars_[v][o] for o in operation_num]) <= 1

my_problem += (
    pulp.lpSum(
        [vars_[v][o] * i for v in val_num for i, o in enumerate(operation_num, 1)]
    )
    == num_operations,
    "Maximum number of operations",
)

my_problem.writeLP("problem.lp")
my_problem.solve()
print("Status:", pulp.LpStatus[my_problem.status])

total_sum = 0
for i, v in enumerate(val_num):
    vv = vals[i]
    for j, o in enumerate(operation_num, 1):
        if pulp.value(vars_[v][o]):
            print(f"We divide {vv} {j} times")
            for _ in range(j):
                vv = remove_last_one(vv)
            break
    total_sum += vv

print("Total sum", total_sum)
```

This prints:

```
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                25.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               2
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Status: Optimal
We divide 7 1 times
We divide 24 2 times
Total sum 6
```

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was a dud.  Here's a better approach that I did formally test and match against the OP's requirements and sample input.

Disclaimer, there may be some optimizations and "pythonic" ways to do things. I'm demonstrating a solution that doesn't leverage any libraries and is easy to read.

The general solution is this.

At each recursive step in the series, the code basically evaluates each of these options

- remove no bits from items[pos] and sum items[pos] with the recursive result on the rest of the list
- remove exactly 1 bit from items[pos] and sum items[pos] with the recursive result on the rest of the list
- remove exactly 2 bits from items[pos] and sum items[pos] with the recursive result on the rest of the list
- remove exactly N bits from items[pos] and sum items[pos] with the recursive result on the rest of the list

It's a similar solution to the classic, "find the max subsequence" type of dynamic programming problem.

**Solution**

I'm making an assumption that all values that came from input are non-negative.

First, some helper functions for counting bits in a number and list as well as removing individual bits.

```
# well known technique for removing the least
# significant set bit in an integer
def strip_lowest_bit(val):
    if (val == 0):
        return 0
    return val & (val-1)

# leveraging the above method we can count the number
# of set bits in an integer
def count_bits(val):
    count = 0
    while val != 0:
        count += 1
        val = strip_lowest_bit(val)
    return count

# same as above but counts the entirity of bits in a list
def count_bits_list(items):
    count = 0
    for item in items:
        count += count_bits(item)
    return count
```

And here's the general solution that uses a cache to avoid duplicate recursion. The cache is just a dictionary that maps between a string (composed of the position, remaining bits in the list, and k bits to be removed).

```
# helper method so we don't recurse into an error state
def can_recurse(items, pos, remaining_bits, k):
    # can't recurse when key values go negative
    # nor can we recurse when there's not enought remaining bits to satisfy k
    if k < 0 or k > remaining_bits or remaining_bits < 0:
        return False
    # if we're at the end, then k must be 0    
    if pos == len(items):
        return k == 0
    return True


def calc_lowest_sum_with_k_bits_removed(items, pos, remaining_bits, k, cache, indent):
    assert(can_recurse(items, pos, remaining_bits,k))

    # avoid duplicated recursion by seeing if we've called this function before with the exact same parameters
    key = str(pos) + "-" + str(remaining_bits) + "-" + str(k)
    if key in cache:
        #print("cache hit at", key)
        return cache[key]
    
    #print(" "*indent, pos, remaining_bits, k)

    # this is how the recursion should safely end when we get to the end of the list and there are no
    # more bits to reduce out of the array
    if pos == len(items) and k==0:
        cache[key] = 0
        return 0

    # optimization. If k is exactly the same as the number of remaining bits
    # we can just return 0
    if k == remaining_bits:
        cache[key] = 0
        return 0
    
    # optimization. If k is zero, then we just return the sum of the remaining items in the array
    # e.g the sum of items[pos..len-1]
    if k == 0:
        quicksum = 0
        for i in range(pos, len(items)):
            quicksum += items[i]
        cache[key] = quicksum
        return quicksum
    
    assert(k > 0)

    # setup up some bookkeeping variables for the next steps    
    val = items[pos]
    bit_count_in_val = count_bits(val)
    best = None

    # continously remove bits within items[pos] and then use recursion to assess the remainder of the array
    # break out of the loop
    bits_removed = 0
    while val > 0:
        val = strip_lowest_bit(val)
        bits_removed += 1
        if can_recurse(items, pos+1, remaining_bits-bit_count_in_val, k-bits_removed):
            tmp = val + calc_lowest_sum_with_k_bits_removed(items, pos+1, remaining_bits-bit_count_in_val, k-bits_removed, cache, indent+1)
            if best==None or tmp < best:
                best = tmp

    # We also need to consider the case where don't pluck any bits from items[pos]
    val = items[pos]
    if can_recurse(items, pos+1, remaining_bits-bit_count_in_val, k):
        tmp = val + calc_lowest_sum_with_k_bits_removed(items, pos+1, remaining_bits-bit_count_in_val, k, cache, indent+1)
        if best==None or tmp < best:
            best = tmp

    assert(best != None)
    cache[key] = best
    return best

def solve(items, k):
    return calc_lowest_sum_with_k_bits_removed(items, 0, count_bits_list(items), k, dict(), 0)
```

Some sample runs:

```
print(solve([8,7], 1))  # prints 7
print(solve([9,6],2))   # prints 6
print(solve([56,3],2))  # prints 35
print(solve([111, 44, 33, 22, 77, 6, 546, 99234, 10, 5], 10)) # prints 308
```

Answer (score -2):

To solve this problem, you can follow these steps:

1. Initialize an empty list to store the binary representations of the given numbers.
2. Iterate through the input numbers and convert each number to binary
   representation while keeping track of the number of set bits (1s) in
   each binary representation.
3. Sort the list of binary representations based on the number of set
   bits in ascending order.
4. Initialize a variable operations to keep track of the number of
   operations performed.
5. Iterate through the sorted list of binary representations, starting
   from the one with the fewest set bits.
6. For each binary representation, calculate the difference between the
   current number of set bits and the target number of set bits (which
   is the number of operations you want to perform).
7. Add the result of the difference to the sum.
8. If the sum exceeds the previous minimum sum, break the loop, as
   further operations will not yield a smaller sum.
9. Return the minimum sum as the answer.

Here's a Python code snippet to implement this algorithm:

```
def min_sum_after_operations(n, k, sequence):
    # Convert each number to binary representation and count set bits
    binary_representations = [(bin(num)[2:], bin(num)[2:].count('1')) for num in sequence]
    
    # Sort the binary representations based on the number of set bits
    binary_representations.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    
    min_sum = float('inf')
    for i in range(n):
        cur_binary, set_bits = binary_representations[i]
        diff = set_bits - k
        
        if diff < 0:
            continue  # Skip if no need to change bits
            
        cur_sum = 0
        for j in range(n):
            if j == i:
                # Calculate the new sum after changing bits
                cur_sum += int(cur_binary, 2) - (2 ** (len(cur_binary) - 1 - cur_binary.rfind('1')))
            else:
                # Add other numbers as they are
                cur_sum += sequence[j]
        
        min_sum = min(min_sum, cur_sum)
    
    return min_sum

# Input
n, k = map(int, input().split())
sequence = list(map(int, input().split()))

# Output
print(min_sum_after_operations(n, k, sequence))
```

You can use this code to calculate the minimum sum of the sequence after performing k operations.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't work for the second example input, returning 13 instead of 6.